# What happens if my public key on server is changed by someone else?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, ssh, rsa

Lets say an attacker gains sudo access to a server holding business critical information. He then changes the public key associated with user Bob to his own public key. He removes all evidence of this action using sudo access and then logs in as Bob with his private key. Now logged in as Bob he does some nasty stuff and this can get Bob in trouble.

Are there any safeguards against this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any safeguards against this kind of behavior?

Other than protecting the server as much as possible? No. And it's not even necessary to change keys or whatever. Root can do everything, even mimicking Bob without key change.

Fail2ban, Snort, SeLinux, etc.etc. ... use them appropriately.

...

For root *logins*, ie. not some bug which allows to do some specific thing, and not necessarily by someone outside of the company ... if you're very concerned about malicious IT staff etc., some sort of "peer review" system could help (and cameras, steel doors, no USB ports, no screws, self-destroying hardware (yes) ... well, you have to know how trustworthy your colleagues are).

Every machine reports root logins to another independent machine (before the person logging in can prevent it; and if the reporting fails the login fails). And every access has to be approved and overseen by a second employee. A logged access without two signatures on the form means there is a breach, everything since then is not reliable anymore.